# Using rsync to write specific data from a complex file structure

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync

I am looking to use rsync to write log data to an external USB drive connected to a linux server.

The command below is writing all data and not just from October.

```
sudo rsync -av -r --progress --include **2018-10-** . /mnt/ext1/
```

The data I need from October can be found in various classes with varying directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -av --include="*/" --include="*2018-10*" --exclude="*" . /mnt/ext1/
```

You should first include everything you want and then exclude the rest. Use **--dry-run** to check if everything is working as you like and **-m** if you don't want the empty directories to be copied.